# find which view was clicked

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller where there are several uiview object. I need to know on which uiview user have tapped. how is this possible? any guidance will help a lot....

Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you can do to get what you wanted ..... In this example i have created 7 views

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer;
UIView* myView;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
{
    gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomthing:)];
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;//or what ever you want

    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, i*30, 30, 28)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    myView.tag = 100+i;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [myView release];
    [gestureRecognizer release];
}
```

Now you need to implement the method like this

```
-(void)doSomthing:(id)sender
{
    UIView* temp = [(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view];
    // here you get the view you wanted
    NSLog(@"view number :%d",temp.tag);
}
```

I think this should help you

Answer (score 1):

Set a tag for every view to keep track of them.

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    // We only support single touches, so anyObject retrieves just that touch from touches
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"view %i", [touch view].tag);
}
```

Comment: how will it tell me which view was tapped. There are about 10-12 views on my page.

Comment: use tag for every view... NSLog(@"view %i", [touch view].tag);

Answer (score 0):

you can add gestures to the uiview objects to find which object has been touched. see the documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

for specific code just comment.

Comment: it can give me the location of touch but how will i get id of the view which was touched. There could be multiple view and i have to perform event on the basis of the view selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

U can probably add a custom button with a tag on top of each view. Then u can know which view is tapped based on the button tag.

pls take a look at this. It may help.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13041-touch-event-subview.html

Comment: it is suggesting me to add a invisible button below the uiview. Is there any other way as it looks very odd to add so many uibuttons unnecessarily on my page.

Comment: ohkk i got it... it took me time but i found out what you meant... thanks